# scrollView not scrolling swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have a scroll view which is not scrolling. Googling seems to indicate that it may be to do with my constraints?

My constraints are as follows:

```
Trailing space to superview  = -16
Leading space to superview = -16
Top space to top layout guide = 0
Bottom space to bottom layout guide = -13
```

I am printing out the scrollview contentSize in the viewDidLayoutSubViews and it is printing out the same value each time i.e:

```
scrollview is (375.0, 356.5)
```

Any idea what the issue may be

Comment: and what about the constraints of your content view, if you don't have it, you should create a view to act as a container for the content

Comment: @Aladin the issue was my bottom constraint. I changed that to zero and it started to scroll. Now though, my issue is that when I lift my finger off the screen, the last few lines of my label can't be seen. So a user has to hold the screen after scrolling to see the content. Does that make sense? It's kind of hard to explain

Comment: Check if you have complains about constraints, and if you can share a screenshot about the issue it will be useful

Comment: @Aladin no issue with constraints in the storyboard or the log. i've added in a view to act as a container for all the components in the scroll view. But that did not help

Comment: the content view should have an width which in your case I guess the width of the super-view (not scroll view) an the width in calculated automatically if you setup the constraints correctly (especially bottom constraint of the content in your case it's a label) can you share a screenshot of the view hierarchy and the issue ?

Comment: the content view does have an equal width to the super view. The width is not an issue. i cannot share a screenshot, the issue is that when a user release their finger after scrolling, that the last couple of lines of the label bounce back up a bit and can't be seen unless the user scrolls again. I would need to make a gif to show you the issue but I won't be dong that

Comment: what about the height constraint of the content view and the label ?

Comment: @Aladin perfect! the issue was my bottom constraint on my label. Thank you.

Comment: glad it helps, please consider accepting my answer to help other users who may run into the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the bottom constraints of the content view (container inside `ScrollView`) in your case it's the `UILabel`

[Apple Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

> To size the scroll view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must
>   either be explicit regarding the width and height of the scroll view,
>   or the edges of the scroll view must be tied to views outside of its
>   subtree.

Useful article : [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)