# Swift: UIScrollView not scrolling vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I have looked at this post : [scrollView not scrolling swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379654/scrollview-not-scrolling-swift)

and I see that the accepted answer suggested the person to add bottom constraints to the `UIScrollViews` subview, `contentView`. I have the following view hierarchy and constraints on each view:

UIView -> UIScrollView(scrollView) -> UIView(contentView)

```
//in the View Controller
self.view.addSubview(coverImage)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

here are the `NSLayoutConstraint`s I add to `scrollView` and `contentView`

```
let tmpViewsDictionary = ["scrollView":self.scrollView, "contentView": self.contentView]

 self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,views: tmpViewsDictionary))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views: tmpViewsDictionary))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[contentView]-0-|",  options: [], metrics: nil, views: tmpViewsDictionary))

 self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[contentView]-0-|", options: [],  metrics: nil, views: tmpViewsDictionary))

self.view.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item :self.contentView, attribute: .Width,  relatedBy: .Equal,  toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width , multiplier: 1,  constant: 0)])
```

I am following the general structure of this tutorial, which fixes the width and has flexible height of the `scrollView`.

http://nscookbook.com/2015/06/ios-programming-recipe-36-a-fixed-width-dynamic-height-scrollview-in-autolayout/

When I add content which exceeds the actual parent view Size, I can't scroll down to see the rest of it. 
It seems that how they make the height dynamic and the width fixed is to simply constraint the child view of `UIScrollView` to have an equal width as the parent of `UIScrollView`. This I do successfully, but the scrolling is still not happening. Thank you for your help!

Here is the full `ViewController` for this view:

https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/90c35c435320e0ec1307e95f575119bf

*UPDATE*

I used Daniels great advice of removing anchoring the bottom of `contentView` to the `scrollView` bottom.

So after debugging the view hierarchy, I see that `contentView` is being set to less than its parent view height, and this seems to stem from an Auto Layout constraint setting the `self.bottom` of `contentView` to `label.bottom` of a `UILabel` which is a child of `contentView`. I never set this constraint and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Here is what that looks like in the ViewHierarchy, where the highlighted `View` is the `contentView` which you see is cut off.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EUREKA. I was foolishly setting the vertical constraint of a child of `contentView` and pinning it to the bottom of `contentView` hence why `contentView` was cut short and wasn't scrolling.

```
"V:|-300-[wikiTitle]|"
```

The last `"|"` cut off the child of my `UIScrollView` short.

Finally I needed to pin the last item of `contentView` to be a specific spacing away from the bottom of `contentView`

Comment: Great! Glad you got it to scroll and identified the exact problem.

Comment: This just saved my bacon. Indeed, a UIScrollView cannot scroll vertically unless constraints are set to dictate how both: **1)** the contentView connects to the scrollView's top & bottom edges; *and* **2)** any subViews of the contentView connect to the contentView's top & bottom edges.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are adding constraints is most likely the cause of your problem.

It appears that you are constraining the bounds of the content view to be the same as the scroll view. In this case, no scrolling can occur due to the constraints.

This is due to your including `self.scrollView` and `self.contentView` within `tmpViewsDictionary`.

In the tutorial that you linked, the dictionary is only being used for adding constraints to the views that are in the content view of the scroll view. It does not include the scroll view or the content view.

Comment: so should I remove the bottom constraint of `contentView` so that it is no longer anchored to the superview of `scrollView`?

Comment: Yes. You will have to eliminate constraints that pin the bottom of `contentView` to the bottom of `scrollView`.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However, when I change the vertical visual format string to `"V:|-0-[contentView]"` I still am not able to scroll down.

Comment: please confer with the github link I made to the whole ViewController file

Comment: You can debug this problem by printing out the frame of each view. This will help you narrow down how the constraints are being interpreted.

Comment: ah! so I see when I capture the view Hierarchy that the `self.bottom = label.bottom` for the `contentView` where label refers to the first child of `contentView`. I never set this constraint programmatically, so is it an AutoLayout constraint?

Comment: It is not a constraint if you didn't set it. You can print the constraints on a view to verify that. If a view doesn't have a constraint it can still get placed within a superview. It seems like you are on the right track to understanding how to go about getting things the way you want them to be.

Comment: but why would it add that constraint if I have `contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` set in `viewDidLoad` lol how do i make that line go away where it restricts contenView to label.bottom as a lower bound

Comment: Perhaps take out the line that starts with `self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|"`. 
I suppose you have a reason for adding constraints programmatically instead of performing your layout using Interface Builder. In my opinion, it would be much easier to do it in IB. I have to to go for now, but I hope you get it worked out.

Comment: thank you for your help! just for reference that doesn't work.